# Amazon EC2 Billing - counted twice for the same data?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

So I've setup an Amazon AWS account for their Free Usage Tier offer.

2 days later I see this in my account info:

- data transfer in under the monthly global free tier: 0.023 GB
- regional data transfer + public / elastic IP data transfers: 0.023 GB

The numbers are OK, because I've been doing downloads to setup my instance.

But while the first item fits into the Free Usage Tier offer, the second does not, and right now my bill is 0.01 USD.

Why is that traffic counted twice?
I am not doing any regional data transfers, so I guess they are billing me for traffic going through an Elastic IP.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to Amazon's EC2 customer service.  Anything you get here is going to be second-hand information, and it could be inaccurate, wrong, or change based on Amazon policies.